# import material package also imports key.dart and framework.dart Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

After creating a new `StatelessWidget`, or a `StatefulWidget`, I decide to import `material` package so I can use `Container` and other widgets.

When I click on the lamp  -> `import material package` it works correctly but also 2 more files have been imported.

To reproduce the error copy-paste the class below, remove all imports and try to import material package.

Example :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/foundation/key.dart'; //not used
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart'; //not used

class Foo extends StatelessWidget {
  const Foo({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

It's weird because these 2 files are blue underlined and if I move my mouse over them this suggestion (for both) is shown :

```
The import of 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' is unnecessary because all of the used elements are also provided by the import of 'package:flutter/material.dart'.
Try removing the import directive.
```

Simply removing them will fix but I would like to understand why this happens. I have installed this extension for `VSCode` called `dart import` maybe the error comes from here?

Comment: I found an issue about this, but there is still no solution
https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/49081